# How to group objects in a dictionary based on their properties and a threshold in Python

Tags: python, list, grouping

I have a list of objects:

```
objects_list= [o1, o2, ...]
```

I would like to group them based on their `location` property. I know that this code will group them based on which ones have the **exact same location** :

```
from collections import defaultdict


groups = defaultdict(list)

for o in objects_list:
    groups[o.location].append(o)

grouped_objects = groups.values()
```

And this gives the expected result but I am now wondering how to tweak this code to add a "threshold" so instead of being grouped based on which ones have the exact same location, they are grouped based on **how close their locations are according to a given threshold**.

Is there anyway I could do that?

Comment: Is location numeric ?

Comment: Sorry about that. THe location is a 3 dimensional float vector. I figured that the answer could be adapted easily from float to a float vector.